# handler for child element when parent have own handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="basket-btn">
<button class="buyout" type="button"><span>Text</span></button>
</div>
```

and two click handler:

```
$('#basket-btn').click(function(){
alert(1);
})

$('.buyout').click(function(){
alert(2);
})
```

The problem in that when I click on div or button rise only first click handler. How to solve it?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
The first click for slide panel, it's moving down and up. The second for button on this slide panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two handlers are working well. ***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/J5GCQ/)*** is a Live Demo.

Make sure to wrap your functions inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your stuff here
});
```

And if you want to prevent first function on button click, you may use `stopImmediatePropagation()`

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/J5GCQ/1/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Comment: `stopImmediatePropogation` this is what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what output you're expecting, but if you want both alerts on click, this seems to work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#basket-btn').click(function(){
           alert(1);
      })

      $('.buyout').click(function(){
           alert(2);
      })
 });
</script>
```

Alternatively, you may want a function which can check if the child button ".-buyout" has been clicked yet or not using data(). This only allows either alert(1), or alert(2) to be displayed. With the following notes:

• alert(2) will fire when the .-buyout button is clicked.

• if div#basket-btn is clicked, and .-buyout hasn't been clicked, alert(1) will fire.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#basket-btn').click(function(){
             if($(this).children().data('clicked') != true) {
                // if child button has not been clicked; do this...
                alert(1);
             }
            })

            $('.buyout').click(function(){
                // if child button is clicked; do this...
                alert(2);
                $(this).data('clicked', true);
            })
        });
</script>
```

The above may be more toward your desired effect.